# ExtJS Number Formatting. 3 digits after decimal

Tags: extjs

Using ExtJS4.1, I have floating point coming as JSON response. How can I format the floating value as 3 digits after decimal points. Find below the example. Please help.

```
enter code here

Example:

{ 
header: 'Total', 
sortable: true, 
dataIndex: 'total', 
field: { xtype: 'numberfield' }, 
renderer: this.onRenderCell 
}

onRenderCell : function(value, metaData, record, rowIndex,colIndex, store, view){
   Ext.util.Format.numberRenderer(value,'0.000');
   return value;            
}
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the [`number(v, format)`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.util.Format-method-number) function, for example:

```
Ext.util.Format.number(1.23456, '0.000');
```

witch will return:

> "1.235"

(The [`numberRenderer`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.util.Format-method-numberRenderer) witch you've tried returns a function)

Answer (score 0):

This functionality is in version 4.2.0.663 totaly buged...

When you do somthing like

```
Ext.util.Format.number("1.23456", '0,000')
```

You get `1` instead `1,234` which is just plainly wrong...

And here is a test case. feel free to correct me if i am wrong.
http://jsfiddle.net/gT9jj/1/

Comment: That would be because it should be `Ext.util.Format.number("1.23456", '0.000')`. You used a comma instead of a period in the template mask.

Comment: puuh, old post. But it is still wrong.. i wanted an output like 1,2345 not 1.2234. Why would i have to supply the inputing format and not the outputing format??

Comment: Might be old, but I did come across it. Someone else might as well - I pointed out the problem, that's all. Sorry, I haven't had the need to investigate about changing the separator.

Comment: Ye the problem is the output seperator which gets printed, the function ignores the global settings and the input settings...

Comment: @MaximKumpan is still right and it's old... The formatting decimal separator of the number will not change with this function. The separator is determined by the settings of the machine you're using. In the format string `,` is defining thousand separator and `.` the decimal separator regardsless of machine settings. `0,000.00`is correct, the one in the fiddle `0.0,000` is not. Comma is always before dot.

Comment: You can see which one your system is using here: http://chris.photobooks.com/tests/overflow/1074660.htm